# Resizing an image similar to CSS3 object-fit: cover

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, carrierwave, minimagick

I'm using Carrierwave and Imagemagick. At times I have images that come in with portrait dimensions. In my uploader file I have images set to `resize_to_fill`.

```
process resize_to_fill: [600, 600]
```

It creates an image to my specifications but as expected it keeps the aspect ratio while filling in the remaining space with a color. Is there a way to fill the newly created image entirely with the original image and center it similar to the way you would with CSS3 [object-fit: cover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)?

Comment: In Imagemagick command line, one would have to crop or extent the image to your desired size. One would be -resize 600x600^ to resize to the `smaller dimension via ^` and let the larger dimension get bigger than 600. Then you would do -gravity center -crop 600x600 to crop out the center of the resized image to the exact size you wanted clipping off the excess.

Comment: How would I translate that indy my uploader file?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know your Carrierwave tool. You will have to look at the documentation and see if there is an equivalent. I suspect you can do that by using RMagick (the Ruby API for Imagemagick)

Comment: All good. Thanks for the tip.